# How to find location of failing import source in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

I have inherited a large angular codebase, and when I run it (using gulp if that matters), the page partially loads, and looking at the dev panel shows that a module has failed to load.

Here is the trace:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>   [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.someModule due
>   to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.someModule' is not available! You 
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering 
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second 
>   argument.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=app.someModule
>   minErr/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>   module/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1986:1
>   ensure@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1910:38
>   module@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1984:1
>   loadModules/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular  /angular.js:4390:22
>   forEach@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:11
>   loadModules@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular  /angular.js:4374:5
>   loadModules/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ang

Is there a way to find out where angular is trying to find the module from (i.e. either the module code, or the code that implicitly relies on that code)?

For what its worth, a simple text search for "someModule" returns far too many hits.

Comment: Make sure that the module is created prior to any dependencies calling it.  So move that file towards the top of you bundle.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm farther away than that. I don't know what file to move. How can I find it?

Comment: That might be hard.  The module definition should be followed by an array of dependencies, so including an open bracket like searching for `.module('someModule', [` might help.

Comment: @ryanyuyu so I should be looking for the definition? If the definition is missing, how can I find the "call site" as it were?

Comment: That I don't know.  You have to ask whoever had the project previously.  You might be paying for their lack of organization.

Comment: unfortunately not an option